# Intellij Idea - disable zoom on vertical edge

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

I use Intellij Idea. When move mouse on vertical edge the editor make zoom on code, how can I disabled this?
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmPKb.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | General | Appearance | Show code lens on scrollbar hover -> disable.